# Where do I store tables (spreadsheets) for a system?

Tags: sql, database

I'm a junior developer and I'm developing a system that allows users to create their own spreadsheets and I don't know if I have to store that information in SQL or create a file with their info and store that HTML file in the database. What is the most efficient way to do it?

Comment: Whatever solution you come to, make sure you strongly check for injection issues, _ESPECIALLY_ if you then interact with a database.

Comment: Also, what spreadsheet language and what type of SQL?

Comment: I'd use **MySQL**, but if there is something significantly better, I'd learn it. @Shawn.

Comment: MySQL is a very good database, especially if you use 8+ versions, but there are others that provide different capabilities. There's really no way to define "better" in DBMSes. It totally depends on your ultimate needs and budget.

Comment: I would always prefer Postgres over MySQL. It's the more mature and feature rich DBMS - but that's my personal opinion (although I know a lot of people that share it)